# Minimum between a list and a number

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm having some complications with a piece of code I'm working on. I need the procedure to take `number (list-of-numbers)` and return the minimum value between the two. So far I have this

```
(define (mini y lon)
 (cond
  [(empty? lon) y]
  [else (min (first (foldr cons lon (list y))) (mini y (rest lon)))]))
```

and I can't figure out the reason why it's not working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is overly complicated, why using `foldr` and `min`, when a simple `min` together with `apply` will do all the work? try this:

```
(define (mini y lon)
  (apply min y lon))
```

... Or you can build a single list with `y` and `lon`, but once again you don't need `foldr` for this, a simple `cons` is all you want:

```
(define (mini y lon)
  (apply min (cons y lon)))
```

... But if you really, really need to use `foldl` (or `foldr`), then it's not required to use `min`, the trick is to pass the right function:

```
(define (mini y lon)
  (foldl (lambda (e a) (if (< e a) e a)) ; foldr will also work
         y
         lon))
```

... Or you could use `min` after all, for a shorter solution. There are so many ways to solve this problem!

```
(define (mini y lon)
  (foldl min y lon)) ; foldr will also work
```

Comment: I thought of this as well but sadly we are required to use foldr or foldl.

Comment: You should state that in the question, otherwise it doesn't make sense to use a fold here

Comment: Thank you, I did a workaround, implementing your solution and came up with this: 
`(define (mini y lon)`
  `(cond`
    `[(empty? lon) y]`
    `[else (apply min (foldr cons lon (list y)))])) `

Edit:
Wow, that's an even better and proper way to do this. Thank you!

Comment: @user2969733 might work, but that's not the idea. When you're using a fold, it takes care of iteration, you don't have to traverse the list explicitly. See my updated answer.

Comment: I love fold, but I really wished it would handle multiple values, so that I could rewrite [a min-max function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19993142/13) using fold. (No, not particularly liking the idea of packing the min and max into a cons, as you'll soon see when you look at the code.)

Comment: There's at least one good reason for @user2969733 to use `fold[lr]` in preference to `(apply n-ary-function ...)`;  implementations probably have a limit on the length of an argument list that can be used with a function, and `apply` with a long list could run afoul of it.  `(fold[lr] n-ary-function ...)` won't have that issue.  There's a bit about it (for Common Lisp) in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19937184/1281433), but similar considerations probably hold for Schemes.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Racket doesn't have that limitation, so there you can use `apply` with reckless abandon. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think [Óscar nailed it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20003531/1565698) for a `racket` solution, but since you tagged the cmpletely different languages **Scheme** and **Lisp** I made som solutions to fit those tags as well.

A R6RS-solution using the native `fold-left` from `(rnrs lists)`

```
#!r6rs ; #!r7rs
(import (rnrs base) (rnrs lists)) ; (import (scheme base))

(define (mini x xs)
  (fold-left min x xs))

;; without fold
(define (mini-simple x xs)
  (apply min x xs))
```

Since you tagged `lisp`, here is a `Common Lisp` version. CL doesn't have `foldl/foldr`, but `reduce` which  replaces both and more:

```
(defun mini (x xs)
  (reduce #'min xs :initial-value x))
```